# How to add a passage/Paragraph type question in Auto-Multiple-Choice?

Tags: exam, auto-multiple-choice, mcexam

I am trying to make add questions to AMC in the following manner

[image]

The question would have a short passage based on which students would have to answer the following questions.

i know the format for general MCQ type question. But how do i handle this?
Some clarifications just in case:

1. Passage questions start in this way only e.g. Paragraph - 3( Q4-Q7 )
2. The order of questions in passage is never changed

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you need to use the following syntax: `\element{<group name>}{<description of question unit>}`. The `<group name>` field can be re-used over an over and is used to group questions together.

For example, "Chapter 1" may have a bank of 20 questions inside it, but each exam may only use 2. Your AMC source file would then have something like:

```
\element{Chapter1}{
\begin{question}{lesson1a} 
  Who had the high ground? 
  \begin{choices} 
    \wrongchoice{Anakin} 
    \correctchoice{Obi-Wan} 
  \end{choices} 
\end{question} }
```

And within the `examcopy` environment you'd have

```
\cleargroup{questions}
\copygroup[2]{Chapter1}{questions}
\copygroup[2]{Chapter2}{questions}
\insertgroup{questions}
```

[Note: this would draw two random questions *per each exam* meaning students have different questions. If you do not want to do that, then do not do this inside the `examcopy` environment, but do it outside and only use the `insertgroup{questions}` within the `examcopy` environment for a standard question list, as depending on your pedagogy.]

For me, I have one file per question unit and within the description for my AMC file, I just have a list of `\element{<group name>}{\input{QuestionFileName}}`

So therefore, what remains is what is in the `<description of question unit>` field. For me, a "question unit" is a single file, although it does not have to be---this just makes re-use easier. The "question unit" in this case is a paragraph, followed by two questions with question order important.

I would make a file with the following:

```
\clearpage %optional
\begin{center}
  \textbf{Paragraph 1 (Q1-Q3)}
\end{center}

The phenomenon of ejection \dots Where $v_o$ represents the threshold frequency of metal.

\begin{question}{paragraph-part1}
  Photoelectrons emitted by green light radiation \dots
  \begin{choices}
    \correctchoice{emit in blue light but not emit in red light}
    \wrongchoice{emit in blue and red light but not emit in yellow light}
    <snip>
  \end{choices}
\end{question}

\begin{question}{paragraph-part2}
  With increase in intensity of radiations $(v > v_0)$
  \begin{choices}
    \correctchoice{Photoelectric current will increase.}
    \wrongchoice{The EMF of photoelectric cell will increase.}
    <snip>
  \end{choices}
\end{question}
```

When this whole section of code is included within a single `element` command, AMC will treat it is a single unit and not break it up. However, ordering of answer choices will still be randomized.

Stylistically, I tend to always place the correct choice as the first item in the `choices` environment as it makes reading off answer histograms easier.

You may also want to redefine some of the lengths between questions so that less space is added. Immediately before the first `\begin{question}` I include

```
\def\AMCbeginQuestion#1#2{}
```

and then redefine it to the default at the last line (after the last `\end{question}`)

```
\def\AMCbeginQuestion#1#2{\par\noindent{\bf Question #1} #2\hspace*{1em}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes looking here later on I solved this in two ways

1st method is by using declaring package cleverref at the end, after babel -

```
\begin{center}
\textbf{Paragraph-1 (Q1-Q3) \cref{\AMCstudentlabel{prez},\AMCstudentlabel{pref},\AMCstudentlabel{Cameroon}}}
\end{center}

\lipsum[5]

\begin{question}{prez}\AMClabel{prez}    
Among the following persons, which one has ever been a President of the French Republic?
\begin{choices}
    \correctchoice{Ren\'e Coty}
    \wrongchoice{Alain Prost}
    \wrongchoice{Marcel Proust}
    \wrongchoice{Claude Monet}
\end{choices}
\end{question}

\begin{question}{Cameroon}\AMClabel{Cameroon}
    Which is the capital city of Cameroon?
    \begin{choices}
        \correctchoice{Yaound\'e}
        \wrongchoice{Douala}
        \wrongchoice{Abou-Dabi}
    \end{choices}
\end{question}

\begin{questionmult}{pref}\AMClabel{pref}  
    Among the following cities, which ones are French prefectures?
    \begin{choices}
        \correctchoice{Poitiers}
        \wrongchoice{Sainte-Menehould}
        \correctchoice{Avignon}
    \end{choices}
\end{questionmult}
```

The advantage of this over the previous answer is that cleverref refers to the proper question no as it would appear in the question paper instead of having to hard code the value

see image

[image]

those questions are actually question no 65 to 67 in the actual question paper

the other method is by using hyperref. pretty much the same function just slightly different syntax ( using \AMCqlabel and \AMCref )

```
\element{general}{
\begin{center}
Paragraph-2(Q4-Q6) \AMCref{q2} to \AMCref{q4}
\end{center}

In 1926, Schrodinger proposed a differential equation for relating energy of a micro system like electron, to its space co-ordinates. When the wave motion is considered in all the three dimensions, Schrodinger wave equation for the electron in hydrogen atom is-

\begin{question}{QuestionAtomicStructureStageB- 4 }\AMCqlabel{q2}
The range polar co-ordinates are
\begin{choicescustom}
\begin{tasks}[label={}](2)
\task \wrongchoice{ (a)  $ 0 \le r \le \infty, 0 \le \theta \le \pi, 0 \le \phi \le \pi $}
\task \wrongchoice{ (b)  $ 0 \le r \le \infty, 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi, 0 \le \phi \le 2\pi $}
\task \correctchoice{ (c*)  $ 0 \le r \le \infty, 0 \le \theta \le \pi, 0 \le \phi \le 2\pi $}
\task \wrongchoice{ (d)  $ 0 \le r \le \infty, 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi, 0 \le \phi \le \pi $} 
\end{tasks}
 \end{choicescustom}
\end{question}

\begin{question}{QuestionAtomicStructureStageB- 5 }\AMCqlabel{q3}
The radial wave function of an electron wave dependent on
\begin{choicescustom}
\begin{tasks}[label={}](2)
\task \correctchoice{ (a*)  n,l only}
\task \wrongchoice{ (b)     n,l,m only}
\task \wrongchoice{ (c)     n only}
\task \wrongchoice{ (d)     all four quantum numbers} 
\end{tasks}
 \end{choicescustom}
\end{question}

\begin{question}{QuestionAtomicStructureStageB- 6 }\AMCqlabel{q4}
Radial part of wave function is zero at r=0 for
\begin{choicescustom}
\begin{tasks}[label={}](2)
\task \wrongchoice{ (a)     s-orbital only}
\task \wrongchoice{ (b)     s and p-orbital only}
\task \wrongchoice{ (c)     s,p and d-orbitals only}
\task \correctchoice{ (d*)  all other than s -orbitals} 
\end{tasks}
 \end{choicescustom}
\end{question}}
```

this also gives the correct question no instead of the hard coded value - see image

[image]

it also gave reference to the correct question no ( 68-70) as you can see.

Hope this helps!